# Problem with mobile images displaying white boxes

Tags: image, mobile, next.js

I am currently running a nextjs server that fetches images from google cloud storage. Everything is working as aspected on desktop and mobile devices when running it from my computer. When I push to production, the images are no longer displayed on mobile (everything works as aspected on desktop computers), Instead little white boxes are shown.

How do I get mobile clients to show the image instead of the little white box?

More Info:

I can hold click the white boxes and open the image in a new tab that shows the correct image.

I am hosting the production build on a server with dokku and using dockerfiles to push the code to the server

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are the images' requests erroring in the Network tab when on mobile? Please provide moree details and a [mre].